# Include then block on a Twig template

Tags: symfony, twig, template-inheritance

None of the previous questions seem to have any information and about a day and a half of random Google searches turns up nothing.

What I am trying to do is this, I have a base.html.twig template and then a folder with several ui elements (slideshows, navigation menus, etc). The idea being I should be able to do this:

**page.html.twig contains**

```
{% extends 'OnMyLemonCommonBundle::base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}

  {% include 'OnMyLemonCommonBundle::features.html.twig' %}

  {% block features %}

    <h2>Featured Articles</h2>

    <li><a href="#">Article 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Article 2</a></li>

  {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

**features.html.twig contains**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
        {% block features %}{% endblock %}
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
        {% block blogs %}{% endblock %}
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
        {% block pictures %}{% endblock %}
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The problem is that this will render as follows:**

```
// Content from top of base.html.twig

<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Featured Articles</h2>

<li><a href="#">Article 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Article 2</a></li>

// Content from bottom of base.html.twig
```

**The question is how would I make this output the following:**

```
// Content from top of base.html.twig

<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">

        <h2>Featured Articles</h2>

        <li><a href="#">Article 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Article 2</a></li>

      </div>

      <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

// Content from bottom of base.html.twig
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, however you can try to use the following

```
{% render'bundle:Controller:method' %}
```

Where you render it like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
          {{ features }}
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this is a solution to your problem

Comment: It does work to a certain extent however we have the problem of the output being escaped as follows `&lt;h1&gt;Welcome&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;hr&gt;`

Comment: Ok I fixed that by using `{% autoescape false %}{% endautoescape %}`

Comment: You can also use the filter `|raw`, like this `{{ featurename|raw }}`

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by having an additional layer of inheritance in your twig files, e.g.:

**features-base.html.twig contains:**

```
{% extends 'OnMyLemonCommonBundle::base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}

  {% include 'OnMyLemonCommYonBundle::features.html.twig' %}

{% endblock %}
```

**page.html.twig contains:**

```
{% extends 'OnMyLemonCommonBundle::features-base.html.twig' %}

{% block features %}

  <h2>Featured Articles</h2>

  <li><a href="#">Article 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Article 2</a></li>

{% endblock %}
```